# Reference section inside table including labels set in that section

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, labels, report

L.S.,

For a modular document where .tex files containing a section can be added and removed, i'm looking for a way to include an overview table of these sections. In this table labels that are set in said sections also need to be displayed.

So for example:

```
\section{Name of finding 1}
\label{not solved}
\label{Critical}
```

which i'm trying to display in a table:

| Finding: | Status: | Severity: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name of finding 1 | Not Solved | Critical |
| Name of finding 2 | Solved | Low |
| Name of finding 3 | Not Solved | Low |
| etc... |  |  |

The sections with the different findings are variable in size and thus the table that needs to be generated should also be generated based on the Sections that are currently present.

The table of contents seems to be able to reference all the different sections, I haven't however found any possibility to customize the TOC and also include different labels that are set in the specific sections.

Are there any packages that make this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea:

You cannot use the `\label` command for this because it already has a meaning and each label must be unique.

But we can define a new command `\Label`, and then the best is to give it the two arguments, instead of using two `\Label` commands.

The `\section` command must be changed to put the section title in a "variable" and the the `\Label` command can pick it up and put it together with its two parameters in a list.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse} % Can be omitted with a recent LaTeX distribution
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlistof{finding}{sec}{List of Findings}

\newcommand{\CurrentSection}{}
\newcommand{\origsection}{}
\let \origsection\section
% Redefine \section to pick up 3 arguments (but not if \section*)
\RenewDocumentCommand \section { s O{#3} m }
{
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}% test if * present
    {\origsection*{#3}}
    {\origsection[#2]{#3}}
  \renewcommand{\CurrentSection}{#3}
}
\newcommand{\Label}[2]{%
  \addtocontents{sec}{\CurrentSection & #1 & #2\\\protect\hline}
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{sec}{%
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
      \protect\hline
      \textbf{Finding:} & \textbf{Status:} & \textbf{Severity:} \\
      \protect\hline
    }
}

\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{sec}{\end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffinding
\newpage

\section{First Section}\Label{Not Solved}{Critical}

\lipsum

\section{SECOND Section}\Label{Not Solved}{Critical}

\lipsum
\section{Third Section}\Label{Solved}{Critical}

\lipsum
\section{Fourth Section}\Label{Not Solved}{Not Critical}

\lipsum
\section{Fifth Section}\Label{Solved}{Not Critical}

\lipsum
\section{SIXTH Section}\Label{Not Solved}{Very Critical}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

It is up to you to get the desired formatting.

[image]

Comment: Hello Pieter, Thank you very much. This is exactly what I am looking for!

I've had some trouble implementing the code in my existing .tex file. I previously posted some wrong conclusions, but i've finally found the culprit. The package lastpage doesn't seem to get along with the code you provided. I don't know exactly why this is, but the code doesnt run with this package loaded. I'm getting the following error:

error: ! Missing } inserted. <inserted text> } l.201 \listoffinding

Just for reference if others would like to use your code.

Thanks again!

Comment: It seems that `tocloft` is incompatible with `lastpage`. Instead of `lastpage` it is advised to use the `totpages` package and then use `\pageref{TotPages}` instead of `\pageref{LastPage}`